# Coherent sheaves and space filling curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

[This](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Enmk/spacefill.pdf) paper constructs smooth space filling curves for smooth varieties over finite fields. Let's say we are working in char $p$ on the variety $X$ then this means that there is smooth curve $C_i$ in $X$ that passes through all $\mathbb{F}_{p^i}$ points of the variety. Let $Z_i=\bigcup_{j=1}^iC_i$ be the closed subset of the variety, now we have this increasing sequence of closed curves $Z_1\subset Z_2\subset \ldots$. You can define the coherent sheaves on this colimit of closed subvariety as the limit of coherent sheaves on $Z_i$. Let's denote this limit of coherent sheaves by $\text{lim}M_{Z_i}$. Let $M_X$ be the category of coherent sheaves on $X$. How does $\text{lim}M_{Z_i}$ compare to $M_X$? is there any chance they are equivalent?